# Redshift handling json oddly

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get the id field ultimately.

I have a debezium message that looks like this in redshift. It's stored as a SUPER type:

```
...
"education_level":{"int":2},"educations":{"string":"[{\"id\": \"South view\", \"type\": \"\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"South view\"}]"},"educations_visible":true,"email":{"string":"mcanad...
```

As you see.. if it's a nested json value the strings are escaped.

Currently I extract it like this:

```
select json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(after), 'educations', 'string') as educations from <table> limit 10;
```

But that gives me this:

```
[]
<null>
"[{\""id\"": \""Holland College\"", \""type\"": \""\"", \""selected\"": true, \""displayName\"": \""Holland College\""}]"
...
```

It's returning VARCHAR values. How can I get at the "id" field? Is there a way to get rid of the escapes? I want to get the id field ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

The value in "string" is a string that is in json format.  You need to parse this into a new super value to get the value of "id".  The json_parse() function performs the reading a string into a super - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_PARSE.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. What code did you have in mind? How does it handle the escapes?

Comment: The "internals" of your Super value is a string that represents JSON - "[{\"id\": \"South view\", \"type\": \"\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"South view\"}]".  To extract a value inside this string you can either try REGEXP (don't) or convert this string into a new Super value using JSON_PARSE().  Is this what you did?